# MySQL 5 - How to check for max number and change max number of connections?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

Am using legacy Spring 4 app which uses MySQL5 on the backend.

When using raw Spring JDBC calls, a bunch of DAOs are throwing the following exception:

```
DAO::org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: 
Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:

Data source rejected establishment of connection, message from server: 
"Too many connections"
```

After scouring the web using Google, I get a lot of different choices for solutions so I rather just ask here.

Tried troubleshooting using the following:

When I issue the following commands inside the database:

```
    show status like 'Conn%';
```

Yields:

```
Connection_errors_accept            0
Connection_errors_internal          0
Connection_errors_max_connections   395711
Connection_errors_peer_address      2
Connection_errors_select            0
Connection_errors_tcpwrap           0
Connections                         423604612
```

A different SQL call:

```
show status like '%onn%';
```

Yields:

```
Aborted_connects                    6857
Connection_errors_accept            0
Connection_errors_internal          0
Connection_errors_max_connections   395711
Connection_errors_peer_address      2
Connection_errors_select            0
Connection_errors_tcpwrap           0
Connections                         423605165
Max_used_connections                1001
Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost   0
Ssl_client_connects                 0
Ssl_connect_renegotiates            0
Ssl_finished_connects               0
Threads_connected                   12
```

Question(s):

1. What is the max amount of connections that can be set by MySQL without it causing any breakage or further performance issues?
2. Checked for max connections like this:

   show variables like "max_connections";

Yields:

```
max_connections 1000
```

A lot of articles on the Internet states that I need to grant / edit the `max_connections` and `max_user_connections` in my.cnf file under the database server. Also, read that I could something like this:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL max_connections = 3000;
```

What is the best course of action to take regarding this issue?

Is it by just simply grant / edit the max_connections and max_user_connections in my.cnf file under the database server as root? Or, are more steps needed?

Comment: Questions 2 and 4 are the same, 3 is not a question at all.

Comment: Whether or not similar questions are posted on Stack Overflow, I did mention "After scouring the web using Google, I get a lot of different choices for solutions so I rather just ask here.", its hard the get the correct answer if there are many different answers to the same question. One of those URLs that stated this question is a duplicate had a a solution that I never read before. So, its unfair to downgrade the Question to begin with.

Comment: Sorry, there is no point in answering the same questions multiple times. These questions have already been asked here on SO and have been answered.

Comment: @Shadow, removed question 3 and represented it as a problem description. I also combined questions 2 & 3.

Comment: I have ignored question 3 and treated 2 and 4 as the same when I chose the duplicates for you. Hence the 2 duplicates.